# how to free different size allocated memory in linked-list in C

Tags: c, matrix, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation

In this question, I'll use parts of my code. so you see what I am trying to explain.
I have this structure which has matrices info and position.

```
typedef struct mylist {
    struct mylist *link;
    int **info;
    int **position;
}Node;
```

Later, I create linked-list (this part of the code is in a loop) with changing variable of "matDim" (let us assume that during each loop the variable is a random integer and the loop repeats 100 times).

```
for(x = 0; x<100;x++){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int matDim = rand();
    matrixA -> link = (Node*) malloc (sizeof (Node));
    matrixA = matrixA -> link;
    matrixA -> info = malloc(sizeof(int*)*(matDim));
    matrixA -> position = malloc(sizeof(int*)*(matDim);
    for(matCount = 0; matCount < (matDim); matCount++){
        matrixA -> info[matCount] = malloc(sizeof(int)*(matDim));
        matrixA -> position[matCount] = malloc(sizeof(int)*(matDim));

    }
 }
```

before this loop I also created

```
 Node *matrixA = (Node*) malloc (sizeof (Node));
matrixA -> info = malloc(sizeof(int*)*(matDim));
matrixA -> position = malloc(sizeof(int*)*(matDim));
for(matCount = 0; matCount < (matDim); matCount++){
    matrixA -> info[matCount] = malloc(sizeof(int)*(matDim));
    matrixA -> position[matCount] = malloc(sizeof(int)*(matDim));
    }
matrixA -> link = NULL;
Node *matrixB = matrixA;
```

my question is, how would you free allocated memory in the link-list if you know that the size of the matrixA -> info and matrix -> position are changing during each loop (there is no specific pattern). By my understanding you have to free each matrixA -> info[x][y] and matrixA -> position[x][y] separately in every node.

I was thinking of including an array[100] in the structure in order to store the sizes since the matrices are squares. However, I was thinking if there is a way of making the program to figure out the size of the matrices and free each variable of matrix.

this is example of two matrix->info (I just putted some random inputs into the memory and printed it in terminal like a matrix)

[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me which variables are changing and what is executed 100 times. In general, every pointer returned by a call to `malloc()` needs to be freed with `free()` later on. So if you have a loop doing 25 `malloc()` you should have a loop doing 25 `free()` to clean it up. How much memory each `malloc()` call allocated doesn't matter, just that every `malloc()` has a corresponding `free()`.

Comment: Where is memory allocated/declared for `matrixA;`?

Comment: I added more code in order to make it clearer what I did and what I am trying to free and the problem is that "matDim" is totally random number, and the memory is also a matrix; I am trying to figure out if it is possible for the program to figure out the size of the matrix which will make it easy to free it

Comment: You need to store `matDim` in each node.

Comment: Side note: You'll get better randomness [not to mention better performance] if you move `srand(time(NULL));` to the top of `main` (i.e. call it only _once_). Then, just call `rand` as you're already doing.

Answer (score 0):

As you allocate matrices with differents size in your Nodes, you have to store this size.
With this, you'll be able to loop on your Nodes to deallocate each cell of your matrices.
In the light of your code, I think you could just use one `int` in your Nodes structure, and this will allow you make all the `free` needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `matdim` element to your node struct to remember the value of `matDim`

Here's the adjusted code. I've compiled but *not* tested it [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct mylist {
    struct mylist *link;
    int matdim;
    int **info;
    int **position;
} Node;

int
main(void)
{
    Node *matrixA;
    int matDim;
    int matCount;
    int x;

    srand(time(NULL));
    matDim = rand();

    matrixA = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    matrixA->info = malloc(sizeof(int *) * matDim);
    matrixA->position = malloc(sizeof(int *) * matDim);

    // NOTE: now node can remember its dimensions
    matrixA->matdim = matDim;

    for (matCount = 0; matCount < matDim; matCount++) {
        matrixA->info[matCount] = malloc(sizeof(int) * matDim);
        matrixA->position[matCount] = malloc(sizeof(int) * matDim);
    }

    matrixA->link = NULL;
    Node *matrixB = matrixA;

    for (x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
        matDim = rand();

        matrixA->link = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        matrixA = matrixA->link;

        // NOTE: now node can remember its dimensions
        matrixA->matdim = matDim;

        matrixA->info = malloc(sizeof(int *) * matDim);
        matrixA->position = malloc(sizeof(int *) * matDim);

        for (matCount = 0; matCount < matDim; matCount++) {
            matrixA->info[matCount] = malloc(sizeof(int) * matDim);
            matrixA->position[matCount] = malloc(sizeof(int) * matDim);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Also, I think there may an additional be a bug or two (a superfluous malloc or two?). I noticed that `info` and `position` are always "in parallel". Whenever I see this, I start thinking "new struct", so I've recoded with that in mind. It may [or may not] fit your needs:

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _info {
    int info;
    int position;
} Info;

typedef struct mylist {
    struct mylist *link;
    int matdim;
    Info **xinfo;
} Node;

int
main(void)
{
    Node *matrixA;
    int matDim;
    int matCount;
    int x;

    srand(time(NULL));
    matDim = rand();

    matrixA = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    matrixA->xinfo = malloc(sizeof(Info *) * matDim);

    // NOTE: now node can remember its dimensions
    matrixA->matdim = matDim;

    for (matCount = 0; matCount < matDim; matCount++)
        matrixA->xinfo[matCount] = malloc(sizeof(Info) * matDim);

    matrixA->link = NULL;
    Node *matrixB = matrixA;

    for (x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
        matDim = rand();

        matrixA->link = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        matrixA = matrixA->link;

        // NOTE: now node can remember its dimensions
        matrixA->matdim = matDim;

        matrixA->xinfo = malloc(sizeof(Info *) * matDim);

        for (matCount = 0; matCount < matDim; matCount++)
            matrixA->xinfo[matCount] = malloc(sizeof(Info) * matDim);
    }

    return 0;
}
```